# How to select four points so that origin is not contained in convex hull of these points?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a regular 12-gon $A_1A_2...A_{12}$ with centre $O$. How to select four points so that centre $O$ doesn't lie in and lie on quadrilateral?

I tried.

With diameter $A_{12}A_6$, consider triangles has one vertex is $A_{12}$ (clockwise). Two remain vertices are choosen from 5 vertices $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$, $A_5$, therefore we have $ \binom{5}{2} =10$. With 12 vertices, we have 120 triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to know the *number of ways* to make such a selection of $4$ nodes.

In counting, we consider $3$ cases separately: the maximum number of sides between any $2$ of the $4$ selected nodes is:

$$(a)\quad 3 : \quad\text{E.g. } A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6 \qquad\text{($3$ sides between $A_3$ and $A_6$)} \\
 (b)\quad 4 : \quad\text{E.g. } A_3,A_4,A_6,A_7 \qquad\text{($4$ sides between $A_3$ and $A_7$)} \\
 (c)\quad 5 : \quad\text{E.g. } A_3,A_4,A_6,A_8 \qquad\text{($5$ sides between $A_3$ and $A_8$)}$$

**Case (a):** Here, all $4$ nodes are consecutive. There are $12$ possible choices for the "start" node and then the rest are uniquely determined. Therefore, the number of such arrangements is $12$.

**Case (b):** Here, we select $4$ of $5$ consecutive nodes. There are $12$ possible choices for the "start" node and then $\binom{3}{2}$ choices for the $2$ "middle" nodes. Therefore, the number of such arrangements is $12\binom{3}{2} = 36$.

**Case (c):** Here, we select $4$ of $6$ consecutive nodes. There are $12$ possible choices for the "start" node and then $\binom{4}{2}$ choices for the $2$ "middle" nodes. Therefore, the number of such arrangements is $12\binom{4}{2} = 72$.

Therefore, the total number of arrangements is

$$12+36+72 = 120.$$